# Android: configuring CICD pipeline to support/ run Integration or UI Tests on Bitrise

Tags: android, continuous-integration, ui-testing, bitrise

I am working on an Android project. I am trying to build a CICD pipeline for my application on the Bitrise. I am following an example on the Bitrise official page, https://devcenter.bitrise.io/testing/device-testing-for-android/. So I added Android Build and [Beta] Virtual Device Testing steps into the workflow in my Bitrise Dashboard.

[image]

But when I build the app, it is only running the tests within the app/src/test folder. I have also written UI Tests using the Expresso framework in the app/src/androidTest folder. But the ones in the app/src/androidTest are not run. What changes do I have to make in order to run those tests?

Answer (score 1):

There are three types of Android tests that can be run with the Virtual Device Testing step:

- Robo, the testing monkey that can be configured for end-to-end testing.
- Game Loop, which I suppose you would use if your app was a game.
- Instrumentation, this will run tests written in androidTest/

In order to run instrumentation tests you will need to build both an app.apk and appTest.apk, conveniently Bitrise has a step called `Android Build for UI Testing`

Make sure to change the `Test type` input variable.