# Integration tests compatibility Android with bitrise

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, bitrise

I would like to start writing integration/unit tests and integrate it with bitrise.
What are one of best options?

Basically I could use one of the libraries i.e. `AndroidX Test` for unit testing and use this tool `Android Unit Test` https://bitrise.io/integrations/steps/android-unit-test

useful testing libraries:
https://learntodroid.com/android-testing-tools/?utm_content=cmp-true

Ok let's say I could write unit tests and integrate it with bitrise using tools above.
..but how is it with integration tests? How to test it to have is bank payment works fine?
How to write integration tests?

I saw also configuration i.e.:
[Android: configuring CICD pipeline to support/ run Integration or UI Tests on Bitrise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60903997/android-configuring-cicd-pipeline-to-support-run-integration-or-ui-tests-on-bi)